# Accessing value from a strange object in matlab

Tags: matlab

When I type in the object in Matlab like this

```
>> a
```

I got following.

```
ans = 

    [6x1004 uint16]
```

How can I access a cell of the object `a`, for example cell of (2,4)?

I tried a(2,4) or a[2,4] in vain.

I understand this is a noob question but have no idea where I can start.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like `a` is a cell variable of size `1x1`. So, did you try indexing with `{}`, eg

```
a{1}(2,4)
```

Answer (score 3):

This should help:

```
>> a = cell(1);
>> a{1} = rand(6,1004);
>> a

a = 

    [6x1004 double]

>> a{1}(1)

ans =

    0.8147
```

When referencing a cell () returns the cell, {} returns the contents of the cell.

Answer (score 2):

To find out the class of an object you can use the [class](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/class.html) function.

```
>> a{1} = uint16(zeros(6,1004));
>> a

a = 

    [6x1004 uint16]

>> class(a)

ans =

cell
```